# Successively attaching maps vs attaching all maps

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory

In the definition of CW complex we need to attaching cells. If there are finitely many $n$ cells, I wonder if there is difference between attaching them successively and attaching them altogether. More precisely and abstractly, Let $i \colon A \to A'$, $j \colon B \to B'$ be two monomorphisms, and $f \colon A\to X, g \colon B \to X$ be morphisms. We then form the pushouts $X_A:= X \coprod_{A}A'$ and $X_{B} : = X\coprod_{B} B'$, and then form $X' = X_A\coprod_{X}X_{B}$. Is it true that
\begin{equation}
X' \simeq X\coprod_{A\coprod B} (A' \coprod B').
\end{equation}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true. To show it, pick a topological space $Y$. We will show that $\mathsf{Top}(X',Y)\cong\mathsf{Top}(X\coprod_{A\coprod B} (A' \coprod B'),Y)$ naturally in $Y$. A map $X'\to Y$ is the data of two maps $f_1\colon X_A\to Y$ and $f_2\colon X_B\to Y$ that agree on their restrictions to $X$. These maps in turn are the data of maps $f_{11}\colon A'\to Y$, $f_{12}\colon X\to Y$ that agree on their restriction to $A$, and of maps $f_{21}\colon B'\to Y$ and $f_{22}\colon X\to Y$ that agree on their restriction to $B$, and additionally we must require $f_{12}=f_{22}$ (this comes from the previous requirement that $f_1$ and $f_2$ agree on their restrictions to $X$). We can combine these maps into maps $g_1\colon A'\coprod B'\to Y$ and $g_2\colon X\to Y$, with $g_1=f_{11}\coprod f_{21}$ and $g_2=f_{12}=f_{22}$. These two maps satisfy precisely that their restrictions to $A\coprod B$ agree; there are no further relations. But this is precisely the data of a map $X\coprod_{A\coprod B} (A' \coprod B')\to Y$, and this proves the natural bijection of the third sentence, so we're done.

There is a second argument we can make, which you may prefer. Consider the commutative diagram
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X @<{\mathrm{id}}<< X @>{\mathrm{id}}>> X\\
@A{g}AA @AAA @AA{f}A\\
B @<<< \varnothing @>>> A\\
@V{j}VV @VVV @VV{i}V\\
B' @<<< \varnothing @>>> A'
\end{CD}
$$
We know that colimits commute with colimits. So we may first take pushouts of all the rows of the diagram and get the diagram
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X\\
@AA{f\coprod g}A\\
A\coprod B\\
@VV{i\coprod j}V\\
A'\coprod B'
\end{CD}
$$
and now take the pushout of this little diagram, giving you $X\coprod_{A\coprod B} (A' \coprod B')$.

Or we may first take the pushouts of the columns of the big diagram, giving us
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X_B@<<< X @>>> X_A
\end{CD}
$$
and now take the pushout of this little diagram, giving us $X'$. The statement that colimits commute with each other says that there is a canonical isomorphism $X'\cong X\coprod_{A\coprod B} (A' \coprod B')$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I found a proof via concrete calculation too, but the abstract reasoning via colimits commuting with colimits is really elegant.